# How to extract a node based on content in XPATH?

Tags: xpath

The URL i am trying to extract the main body text is

indiainfoline"DOT"com/Markets/News/Cement-shares-build-on-budget-expectations/3567698750

Below is the text string that i am seraching for --

> "UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%), Ambuja
>   Cements (up 2.15%), ACC (up 1.72%),
>   India Cements (up 1.50%), Madras
>   Cement (up 1.68%), Prism Cement (up
>   1.81%), JK Lakshmi Cements (up 2.11%) and Shree Cement"

XPATH query i am using is

```
sampleBody =  hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("
                   //*[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')]").InnerText;
```

I am getting the entire page instead of just the text of that particular node.

Can any one please suggest the reason?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am getting the entire page instead
>   of just the text of that particular
>   node.
>
> Can any one please suggest the reason?

This XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')]
```

It means: *any child element having `'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)'` as part of its **string value***. This is because `.` would be expanded to `self::node()` an then cast with `string()` as argument for `contains()`.

So, if there is such string in the document content, **the root element will have it as part of its string value**.

If you need the innermost element having such string value, use this XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')]
   [not(*[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')])]
```

**Colloquial Meaning:** I have the string and none of my children does.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alejandro, Same way can i go few levels up from the innermost element till i find a Div node? Because sibblings of the FOUND inner most node also has data that i need to capture. So i need to go up from the inner most node till i find a div and then capture the entire text of the div. Hope you understood.

Comment: @Krishna Chaitanya M: You could seletc the innermost `DIV` element with the same logic: `//DIV[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')][not(.//DIV[contains(.,'UltraTech Cement (up 2.77%)')])]`